# Comparar datos del mes con query en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi actual consulta es la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT Fecha,
    ISNULL([ELFO_006_Oficinas], 0) AS 'ELFO_006_Oficinas',
    ISNULL([ELFO_007_Rim], 0) AS 'ELFO_007_Rim',
    ISNULL([ELFO_008_ED], 0) AS 'ELFO_008_ED',
    ISNULL([ELFO_009_FBW], 0) AS 'ELFO_009_FBW',
    ISNULL([ELFO_010_Disco], 0) AS 'ELFO_010_Disco'
 FROM
(
    SELECT Fecha, Linea, Dato FROM Dato_Medidor
) src
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Dato) FOR Linea IN ([ELFO_006_Oficinas],
    [ELFO_007_Rim], [ELFO_008_ED], [ELFO_009_FBW],
    [ELFO_010_Disco])
) AS pvt

WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '01/01/2023' and '01/02/2023'
ORDER BY Fecha
```

Ahora me están pidiendo que compare el dato que recibo en *[ELFO_006_Oficinas]* con el mismo dato del día anterior y el resultado de la resta de estas dos cantidades sería mi resultado saliente. Solo que esto sería utilizando un filtro de fechas.

Por ejemplo en la consulta yo tengo el filtro de 01/01/2023 al 01/02/2023, entonces sería comparar el 01 de enero con el 02 de enero y el 02 de enero con el 03 de enero, así sucesivamente hasta el 01 de febrero.

---

Respondiendo a [@Luis_Cazares](/users/117337/), no me está mostrando los datos de la fecha anterior.

Este es el resultado que me arroja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la consulta que estoy utilizando

```sql
SELECT dm.Fecha,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas' THEN dm.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas' THEN dp.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas' THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL( dp.Dato, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'      THEN dm.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_007_Rim,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'      THEN dp.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_007_Rims_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'      THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL( dp.Dato, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_007_Rim_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'       THEN dm.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_008_ED,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'       THEN dp.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_008_EDs_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'       THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL( dp.Dato, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_008_ED_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'      THEN dm.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_009_FBW,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'      THEN dp.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_009_FBWs_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'      THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL( dp.Dato, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_009_FBW_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'    THEN dm.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_010_Disco,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'    THEN dp.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_010_Discos_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'    THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL( dp.Dato, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_010_Disco_Diferencia
FROM Dato_Medidor dm
LEFT JOIN Dato_Medidor dp ON DATEADD( DAY, -1, dm.Fecha) = dp.Fecha
                         AND dm.Linea = dp.Linea
                         AND dp.Fecha BETWEEN DATEADD( DAY, -1, '{Root Container.Popup Calendar.date}') AND DATEADD( DAY, -1, '{Root Container.Popup Calendar 1.date}') AND DATEPART(HOUR, dp.Fecha) = 7 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, dp.Fecha) = 0
WHERE dm.Fecha BETWEEN '{Root Container.Popup Calendar.date}' AND '{Root Container.Popup Calendar 1.date}' AND DATEPART(HOUR, dm.Fecha) = 7 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, dm.Fecha) = 0
GROUP BY dm.Fecha
ORDER BY dm.Fecha;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen varias formas de hacerlo. Para hacerlo con pivot, podrías hacer la consulta de ambos rangos de fechas y luego unirlos con un JOIN por fechas sumando un año a la fecha anterior.

```
WITH cteDatos AS(
    SELECT Fecha,
        ISNULL([ELFO_006_Oficinas], 0) AS 'ELFO_006_Oficinas',
        ISNULL([ELFO_007_Rim], 0) AS 'ELFO_007_Rim',
        ISNULL([ELFO_008_ED], 0) AS 'ELFO_008_ED',
        ISNULL([ELFO_009_FBW], 0) AS 'ELFO_009_FBW',
        ISNULL([ELFO_010_Disco], 0) AS 'ELFO_010_Disco'
        FROM
            (
                SELECT Fecha, Linea, Dato FROM Dato_Medidor
            ) src
        PIVOT
            (
                MAX(Dato) FOR Linea IN ([ELFO_006_Oficinas],
                [ELFO_007_Rim], [ELFO_008_ED], [ELFO_009_FBW],
                [ELFO_010_Disco])
            ) AS pvt

    WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal
),
cteDatos_Anterior AS(
        SELECT DATEADD( YY, 1, Fecha) AS Fecha,
        ISNULL([ELFO_006_Oficinas], 0) AS 'ELFO_006_Oficinas',
        ISNULL([ELFO_007_Rim], 0) AS 'ELFO_007_Rim',
        ISNULL([ELFO_008_ED], 0) AS 'ELFO_008_ED',
        ISNULL([ELFO_009_FBW], 0) AS 'ELFO_009_FBW',
        ISNULL([ELFO_010_Disco], 0) AS 'ELFO_010_Disco'
        FROM
            (
                SELECT Fecha, Linea, Dato FROM Dato_Medidor
            ) src
        PIVOT
            (
                MAX(Dato) FOR Linea IN ([ELFO_006_Oficinas],
                [ELFO_007_Rim], [ELFO_008_ED], [ELFO_009_FBW],
                [ELFO_010_Disco])
            ) AS pvt

    WHERE Fecha BETWEEN DATEADD( YY, -1, @FechaInicial) AND DATEADD( YY, -1, @FechaFinal)
)
SELECT d.Fecha,
       d.[ELFO_006_Oficinas]                                     AS 'ELFO_006_Oficinas',
       a.[ELFO_006_Oficinas]                                     AS 'ELFO_006_Oficinas_Anterior',
       d.[ELFO_006_Oficinas] - ISNULL( a.[ELFO_006_Oficinas], 0) AS 'ELFO_006_Oficinas_Diferencia',
       d.[ELFO_007_Rim]                                          AS 'ELFO_007_Rim',
       a.[ELFO_007_Rim]                                          AS 'ELFO_007_Rim_Anterior',
       d.[ELFO_007_Rim] - ISNULL( a.[ELFO_007_Rim], 0)           AS 'ELFO_007_Rim_Diferencia',
       d.[ELFO_008_ED]                                           AS 'ELFO_008_ED',
       a.[ELFO_008_ED]                                           AS 'ELFO_008_ED_Anterior',
       d.[ELFO_008_ED] - ISNULL( a.[ELFO_008_ED], 0)             AS 'ELFO_008_ED_Diferencia',
       d.[ELFO_009_FBW]                                          AS 'ELFO_009_FBW',
       a.[ELFO_009_FBW]                                          AS 'ELFO_009_FBW_Anterior',
       d.[ELFO_009_FBW] - ISNULL( a.[ELFO_009_FBW], 0)           AS 'ELFO_009_FBW_Diferencia',
       d.[ELFO_010_Disco]                                        AS 'ELFO_010_Disco',
       a.[ELFO_010_Disco]                                        AS 'ELFO_010_Disco_Anterior',
       d.[ELFO_010_Disco] - ISNULL( d.[ELFO_010_Disco], 0)       AS 'ELFO_010_Disco_Diferencia'
FROM      cteDatos d
LEFT JOIN cteDatos_Anterior a ON d.Fecha = a.Fecha
ORDER BY Fecha;
```

Personalmente, prefiero una opción que llamo agregado condicional que puede hacerlo de forma más directa. Igualmente hacemos un JOIN por fecha cambiando el año, pero además haciendolo por medio de la línea.

```
SELECT dm.Fecha,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas' THEN dm.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas' THEN dp.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas' THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL( dp.Dato, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'      THEN dm.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_007_Rim,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'      THEN dp.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_007_Rims_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'      THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL( dp.Dato, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_007_Rim_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'       THEN dm.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_008_ED,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'       THEN dp.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_008_EDs_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'       THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL( dp.Dato, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_008_ED_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'      THEN dm.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_009_FBW,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'      THEN dp.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_009_FBWs_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'      THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL( dp.Dato, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_009_FBW_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'    THEN dm.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_010_Disco,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'    THEN dp.Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_010_Discos_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'    THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL( dp.Dato, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_010_Disco_Diferencia
FROM Dato_Medidor dm
LEFT JOIN Dato_Medidor dp ON DATEADD( YY, -1, dm.Fecha) = dp.Fecha
                         AND dm.Linea = dp.Linea
                         AND dp.Fecha BETWEEN DATEADD( YY, -1, @FechaInicial) AND DATEADD( YY, -1, @FechaFinal)
WHERE dm.Fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal
GROUP BY dm.Fecha
ORDER BY dm.Fecha;
```

Aunque también se me ocurrió una forma de hacerlo sin ningún JOIN, aunque le lógica se vuelve un poco más complicada.

```
WITH cteDatos AS(
    SELECT  IIF( Fecha < @FechaInicial, DATEADD( YY, 1, Fecha), Fecha) AS Fecha,
            Linea,
            SUM( Dato) Dato,
            IIF( Fecha < @FechaInicial, 1, 0) AS Anterior
    FROM Dato_Medidor
    WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal
    OR    Fecha BETWEEN DATEADD( YY, -1, @FechaInicial) AND DATEADD( YY, -1, @FechaFinal)
    GROUP BY IIF( Fecha < @FechaInicial, DATEADD( YY, 1, Fecha), Fecha),
             Linea,
             IIF( Fecha < @FechaInicial, 1, 0)
)

SELECT Fecha,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas' AND Anterior = 0 THEN Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas' AND Anterior = 1 THEN Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas' THEN Dato * IIF(Anterior = 1, -1, 1) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'      AND Anterior = 0 THEN Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_007_Rim,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'      AND Anterior = 1 THEN Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_007_Rims_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'      THEN Dato * IIF(Anterior = 1, -1, 1) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_007_Rim_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'       AND Anterior = 0 THEN Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_008_ED,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'       AND Anterior = 1 THEN Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_008_EDs_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'       THEN Dato * IIF(Anterior = 1, -1, 1) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_008_ED_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'      AND Anterior = 0 THEN Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_009_FBW,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'      AND Anterior = 1 THEN Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_009_FBWs_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'      THEN Dato * IIF(Anterior = 1, -1, 1) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_009_FBW_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'    AND Anterior = 0 THEN Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_010_Disco,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'    AND Anterior = 1 THEN Dato                       ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_010_Discos_Anterior,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'    THEN Dato * IIF(Anterior = 1, -1, 1) ELSE 0 END) AS ELFO_010_Disco_Diferencia
FROM cteDatos
GROUP BY Fecha
ORDER BY Fecha;
```

Hice pruebas en una tabla con 60 000 filas. Todos muestran el mismo rendimiento, pero eso puede ser distinto en un ambiente real.

Aquí dejo mi código para generar el entorno de pruebas.

```
CREATE TABLE Dato_Medidor(
    Fecha   datetime,
    Linea   varchar(30),
    Dato    float
);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_Dato_Medidor ON Dato_Medidor( Fecha, Linea);

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 n
    FROM E4
)
INSERT INTO Dato_Medidor
SELECT DATEADD( DD, n, '20210101'),
        Linea,
        ABS( ROUND( RAND( CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000, 4))
FROM cteTally
CROSS JOIN (VALUES( 'ELFO_006_Oficinas'),
                    ('ELFO_007_Rim'),
                    ('ELFO_008_ED'),
                    ('ELFO_009_FBW'),
                    ('ELFO_010_Disco'),
                    ('ELFO_011_Falso')) x(Linea);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría un `left join` a la misma tabla pero desplazando un día (con `DATEADD` -1day). Así junto el día con el día siguiente en una misma fila

```
SELECT D.fecha as desde, H.fecha as hasta, (H.valor - D.valor) as diferencia
from tabla as D
left join tabla  as H on D.fecha = DATEADD(day,-1,H.fecha)
```

Digamos que tengo estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]